# Change Label of custom post type

Tags: plugin-development, wp-admin

I have created a custom post type by the name of Teams. Listing page looks like this[image]

How can I change this highlighted `title` label?

Is there any hook for this that you know of?

Answer (score 1):

The `list_table_primary_column` hook might be the one to go with, i.e:

```
add_filter('list_table_primary_column', 'teams_table_primary_column', 10, 2);

function teams_table_primary_column($colname, $screen_id) {
    if($screen_id == 'teams' && $colname == 'Title') {
        return "New column name";
    }
}
```

Note: this is completely untested, let me know how it goes!

[Reference](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/da7a80d67fea29c2badfc538bfc01c8a585f0cbe/wp-admin/includes/class-wp-list-table.php#L992)

Comment: I tested it. It works.